# Repeat GUI-block in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI where a user can select a value from a listbox and store it. The user will have multiple things to select, but only one selection per listbox. At the moment I have one listbox with the nessecary properties. It is generated with this code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent #the root
        #select setup
        list = {"Setup 1","Blue Setup","Setup 12","Broken Setup","Noise Generator"}
        msg = "Select Setup"
        self.SVAL = 0;
        self.Sframe = Frame(parent)
        self.Sframe.pack()
        self.Slabel = Label(self.Sframe,text=msg)
        self.Slabel.pack()
        self.Sbox = Listbox(self.Sframe)
        for item in list:
            self.Sbox.insert(END,item)
        self.Sbox.pack()
        self.Sbut = Button(self.Sframe,text="select", command=self.Sselect)
        self.Sbut.pack()
        self.Smess = Message(self.Sframe,text="Go")
        self.Smess.pack()

    def Sselect(self):
        print(self.Sbox.curselection())
        self.SVAL = self.Sbox.curselection()
        self.Smess.configure(text=self.Sbox.get(self.SVAL[0]))


root = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to generate a second frame at the right from it, but it would be nice if I don't have to repeat the code. The goal is to repeat this GUI-block and only change the list and msg variable so I would have something like

```
list = {"Setup 1","Blue Setup","Setup 12","Broken Setup","Noise Generator"}
msg = "Select Setup"
self.S = generateblock(list,msg)
list = {"Joe","George","Harry"}
msg = "Select User"
self.U = generateblock(list,msg)
```

I hope this is possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Put the code in a function, then call the function as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "list" is not a list and will yield an error.  You also have to keep track of which listbox the selection number is from.  A simple modification to show the concept.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent #the root
        self.listbox_instances=[]
        #select setup
        list_of_choices = [["Setup 1","Blue Setup","Setup 12","Broken Setup",
                           "Noise Generator"],
                          ["test 2a", "test 2b", "test 2c"],
                          ["test 3a", "test 3b", "test 3c"],]
        msg = "Select Setup"
        ##self.SVAL = 0;
        for ctr in range(3):
            self.Sframe = Frame(parent)
            self.Sframe.grid(row=0, column=ctr)
            self.Slabel = Label(self.Sframe,text=msg)
            self.Slabel.pack()
            self.Sbox = Listbox(self.Sframe)
            for item in list_of_choices[ctr]:
                self.Sbox.insert(END,item)
            self.Sbox.pack()
            self.listbox_instances.append(self.Sbox)

            ## send the listbox number with the command call
            self.Sbut = Button(self.Sframe,text="select",
                               command=partial(self.Sselect, ctr))
            self.Sbut.pack()
            self.Smess = Message(self.Sframe,text="Go")
            self.Smess.pack()

    def Sselect(self, this_num):
        print("box_num=%d & item num=%s" % (this_num,
               self.listbox_instances[this_num].curselection()))
##        self.SVAL = self.Sbox.curselection()
##       self.Smess.configure(text=self.Sbox.get(self.SVAL[0]))


root = Tk()
myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```